# Is an explicit KEY redundant if it is covered by a UNIQUE KEY?

Tags: mysql, index

I am auditing an application which I've been developing over the course of several weeks. I've noticed this in `CREATE TABLE`:

```
UNIQUE KEY `baz_3` (`baz`,`foo`,`bar`),
KEY `baz` (`baz`),
```

**Is the explicit `KEY` redundant, as I think it is?** I just want to make sure before I `DROP` it. From what I've read I do believe that the  `UNIQUE KEY` will act as an Index when the application performs `WHERE baz='something'` but MySQL seems so intricate that I find it prudent to ask here first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can drop it because `baz` and `baz_3` have identical leading columns. This scenario is known as having redundant indexes.

**However**, be careful that the key `baz` is not being used to support a foreign key constraint if the table is InnoDB. See my post [Do I have duplicate key indexes?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9009/do-i-have-duplicate-key-indexes/9010#9010)

If the table is MyISAM, go ahead and drop it with confidence. The MySQL Query Optimizer will use the UNIQUE KEY `baz_3` for query optimization in its execution plans.

If you want to locate all tables with redundant indexes, see this post : [MySql - find redundant indexes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11704/mysql-find-redundant-indexes)

Comment: Thank you Rolando, it is exactly for this type of info (in the links) that I came here. In fact, the table is InnoDB but it is not (currently) using foreign keys.